# Storing and getting data in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows

I have created a Windows phone app based on a quiz game. I want that when the user give the correct answer for some question then a small tick mark will be permanently on in the tab of the question.
I want to store score for every question so that i can display that in a place name as 'your score'. And that score will not be reset even if the app is closed.

Comment: Have you ever done any research for this? You can find tons of answers at Google or even on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

you could use app IsolatedStorage for saving the file.

[reference](http://albrecht-schmidt.blogspot.in/2011/04/wp7-tutorial-part-4-storing-data-on.html)

```
 #region Save and Load Parameters from the Application Storage

    void saveToAppStorage(String ParameterName, String ParameterValue)
    {
        // use mySettings to access the Apps Storage
        IsolatedStorageSettings mySettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        // check if the paramter is already stored
        if (mySettings.Contains(ParameterName))
        {
            // if parameter exists write the new value
            mySettings[ParameterName] = ParameterValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // if parameter does not exist create it
            mySettings.Add(ParameterName, ParameterValue);
        }
    }

    String loadFromAppStorage(String ParameterName)
    {
        String returnValue = "_notSet_";
        // use mySettings to access the Apps Storage
        IsolatedStorageSettings mySettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        // check if the paramter exists
        if (mySettings.Contains(ParameterName))
        {
            // if parameter exists write the new value
            mySettings.TryGetValue<String>(ParameterName, out returnValue);
            // alternatively the following statement can be used:
            // returnValue = (String)mySettings[ParameterName];
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Your code lacks `mySettings.Save()` - without this data won't be preserved betweend separate runs of the App. I'm not sure if in OP's case using IsolatedStorageFile or database wouldn't be better. In case there are plenty of questions, they can be for example serialized as a Dictionary or List - in case ISS it can also be done, but IMO ISS shouldn't be used to store 'large' amount of data.